# AmE_ she (went out)/ (has gone out) to the supermarket

Tags: tense, american-english, present-perfect, past-simple

I know that AmE speakers tend to use the simple past in situations in which we should use the present perfect. I would like to ask if in the US, natives would use simple past in this context:

A husband is looking for his wife. He meets the daughter and asks

> The father: Where is your mum?
>
> The daughter:___________________. I think she'll be home soon.

(1) She **went out** to the supermarket.

(2) She **has gone out** to the supermarket.

I think that both are good in the US, but I am not sure.

Comment: I (an American) would only use the simple past in this sentence. I don't know if BrE speakers would disagree.